# jquery datepicker - show week number if has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jquery ui datepicker but I want to show the week number only if the input element has a specific class...

Here's what I've tried but with no success...

```
$(".myCal").datepicker({
    showWeek: function(dateText, inst) { $(this).hasClass("showWeek"); }
});
```

Comment: Are you missing a "return" in your anonymous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As class selector is used, **each** method is required to iterate over all matching elements and then use $(this).

```
$(".myCal").each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        showWeek: $(this).hasClass('showWeek')
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ubw3L/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myCal').each(function () {
  $(this).datepicker({
    showWeek: $(this).hasClass('showWeek');
  });
});
```

Comment: Your edited answer is a copy of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15951644/504368). No problem, just for the fair play :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$(".myCal").datepicker({
    showWeek: $(this).hasClass("showWeek");
});
```

As the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showWeek) states, `showWeek` accept boolean value.